# insert element on the half div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to insert an element ( a div for example ) on the half of the div and just after a double `<br />` element

here my code it just an example the div could be longer or smaller

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );

        var h_div = $('#my_post').height();

    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id='my_post'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            <br /><br />

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            <br /><br />

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            <br /><br />


        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Should I use position() function in Jquery to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by half the div? And double element?

Comment: can you clarify what you want to insert after the double `br`

Comment: Do you want to add element after 1st paragraph?

Comment: What are you trying to add? If the paragraphs are different sections, maybe have them in their own divs, as then adding an element after each one would be easy.

Comment: Instead of double breaks, your post should contain paragraphs. Since it is `lorem ipsum` guess it is not done yet, so do it correct way.

Comment: I mean in this case after the 2nd paragraph the heigh of my div is 360px so the half is in the middle of the 2nd paragraph so i need to insert my element after this second paragraph

Answer (score 2):

How about:

`$('br:eq(1)', '#my_post').after('<div>whatever ...</div>');`

This would insert a div within #my_post after the second <br>

Ok, let's break that down a bit more:

`$('br')` is a jquery selector that returns a collection of all <br> elements in the document. Since you need only the <br> in a specific container we limit the search to this container: `$('br', '#my_post')`. Now you have a collection of all <br> elements within the div #my_post. Now we add the filter :eq() which selects only a specific one of the <br> elements. Since :eq() is zero index based we use the number 1 to get the second <br> element.

Now we use the jquery method `.after()` to insert content after the element we specified with the selector `$('br:eq(1)', '#my_post')`

You might want to take a look at the jquery docs: http://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: Try to explain your code a bit more thoroughly, so that lads from the future - and OP - understand why this code works ;)